# Whonix with http server not reachable

Tags: onion-services, configuration, whonix

I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.linuxx.eu/2014/05/how-to-host-your-own-tor-hidden-service.html) on how to setup Whonix with a `lighttp` server so I can host my own tor website.

I did all the steps described in the tutorial, but when I try to visit my tor website (through another machine) then it (eventually) says ***The connection has timed out***.

And I'm sure my `lighttpd` webserver is running. Made sure by doing a `ps ax | grep ligh`.

My `torrc` is exactly as it says in the tutorial:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ 
HiddenServicePort 80 192.168.0.11:80
```

Not sure about the IP address `192.168.0.11` though. Should that be something else?

If not, anyone any idea why my tor website isn't showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whonix has it's own documentation for this.

https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Hidden_Services#Hidden_Webserver

I would recommend that instead, because that is up to date information.

The ip they say that you should point to there is:

HiddenServicePort 80 10.152.152.11:80

You can also double check the ip inside the whonix workstation with the command 'ifconfig'.

Comment: I did try `ifconfig` before, but that showed the ip `10.152.152.10` and that one didn't work. I just tried what you said `10.152.152.11` and that one does work!